# Getting Illegal option : D while running docker image

Tags: spring-boot, docker, dockerfile

While running docker image with either of these commands

```bash
sudo docker run -p 9090:8181 abc-docker-image
docker run -p 9090:8181 -it abc-docker-image
```

Docker File:

```bash
FROM openjdk:17
EXPOSE 8181
ADD target/abc-0.0.1-release.jar target/abc-docker
ENTRYPOINT [ "jar","Dspring.profile.active=local","-jar","/abc-0.0.1-release.jar"]
```

What is this issue here in the code?

It has to run like a normal docker image but getting illegal option:D

Comment: You don't have a hyphen at the start of the `-Dspring.profile.active=...` option; is that the thing that's missing?  What is the exact text of the error you're getting?

Comment: It needs to be `-Dkey=value` not `Dkey=value`.

Comment: And you should be running `java` not `jar` as your executable.